# Finding my old closed questions.

Tags: support, search, closed-questions

When I first signed up here I posted a question about the monotone class theorem that was closed. Is there a way to find it or is it gone?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148514/question-about-monotone-class-theorem-in-big-rudin), automatically deleted nine days after the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By searching for [user:me closed:1](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+closed%3A1) you can find all your closed questions. To find more about various similar options, have a look at [advanced search tips](https://math.stackexchange.com/search). Of course, you can add other keywords or search options if you need to restrict the number of results.

It is possible to find your own deleted posts by searching for [deleted:1](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3A1), but it only works for [10k+ users](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). For more details, see: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13948/is-there-any-way-to-see-my-deleted-questions-or-answers

Answer (score 0):

If it is not on your user page, it is deleted.